# Get comma separated string from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I'm saving a string from PHP to MySQL like this..

```
$groupid = "13, 14, 15, 16"
$write = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','$groupid')");
```

I'm then trying to extract data from the table if $a = "15"

```
$extract = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ustaffid='$ustaffid' AND groupid='$a'");
```

How can I easily match what's in $groupid to $a, while extracting it? Can I do that with MySQL?

Comment: Did you consider to restructure your database schema to conform to your needs? It looks to me like you need 1:many relationship here.

Comment: Indeed, as will be said by many, this highlights a flaw with your design. Take advantage of the inherent properties of relational databases and use multiple tables. You'll only run into difficulty with selects, updates, joins etc. They will all become overly complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function here.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE ustaffid='$ustaffid' 
        AND FIND_IN_SET('$a', groupid) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$a` contains only one id I would suggest seperating it into multiple records, because in string search (/ select) is slower.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if having spaces in the `groupid` columns would affect the `find_in_set` MySQL function, and as @PeeHaa notes searching inside a string is slower and is hard to optimize with indexes.

You should really consider modifying the database schema and normalize it so that instead of saving multiple values in a column, use a dependent table and relate multiple rows to the main table for each `groupid` value.  That's what relational databases are for.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @ecchymose's answer, you can use a regex instead of LIKE.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ustaffid='$ustaffid'
AND groupid RLIKE '(^|, )$a(, |$)'
```

Note: You may need to escape the last `$` with a `\`.

Note 2: This isn't the optimal solution.  You should really have a separate row for each ID (with the ID being the PRIMARY key).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ustaffid='$ustaffid' 
AND groupid LIKE '%$a,%'
```

But you have to end your string with a comma at the end.

Comment: What if the value of `$a` was the last element of the list (i.e., there's no trailing comma at the end)?

Comment: it wouldn't find it.  That's why if you're searching WITH the separator, each elements must have one after it...  not an optimal solution, but if you're in a hurry...